# Fetch data from an array with elements of second array

Tags: arrays, swift, xcode, filter

I have one array "users" with all user data and and second array "userIds" having user's id. I have to fetch User from "users" array using "userIds" array

```
struct User {
    let name: String
    let id: Int
}

let users: [User] = [User(name: "a", id: 1), 
                     User(name: "b", id: 2), 
                     User(name: "c", id: 3), 
                     User(name: "d", id: 4), 
                     User(name: "d", id: 5)]

let userIds = [2,3,2,5]
```

result array that I want is :

```
[User(name: "b", id: 2),
 User(name: "c", id: 3),
 User(name: "b", id: 2),
 User(name: "d", id: 5)]
```

so it can have duplicate data according to the data in "userIds".

Now I tried using Higher order function `filter`:

```
let result = users.filter { (user) -> Bool in
    return userIds.contains(user.id)
}
```

but this removes the duplicate data and the output is :

```
[User(name: "b", id: 2),
 User(name: "c", id: 3),
 User(name: "d", id: 5)]
```

One approach that I tried is using for loop :

```
var result = [User]()

for i in userIds {
    result.append(users.filter({ $0.id == i }).first!)
}
```

which gives the desired output but if there is a better approach please suggest.

Comment: A loop looks like a good solution to me. This isn’t about filtering for me but rather to fetch from a source (array1) using a request (array2)

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion @JoakimDanielson. Please look at the answer that I have added.

Comment: You should probably use structs instead of dicts, for `array1`. Otherwise you're just going to be in a bottomless pit of force casts, type errors and crashes.

Comment: @Alexander-ReinstateMonica: it's struct only in the project. To ask question I created a sample one in playground.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can solve this using `first(where:)` to search through `users`:

```
let result = userIds.compactMap { desiredDataValue in
    users.first(where: { $0.id == desiredDataValue })
}
```

But if you're doing this a lot, it would probably speed things up if you built a datastructure that allows for fast lookup by the "id" value. You should compare the performance for yourself, and see if you do this enough/frequently enough for it to be worthwhile:

```
let dictsByData = Dictionary(uniqueKeysWithValues:
    users
        .lazy
        .map { dict in
            (key: dict.id, value: dict)
        }
)

let result = userIds.compactMap { desiredDataValue in dictsByData[desiredDataValue]! }
result.forEach { print($0) }
```

Comment: Thanks a ton buddy. I loved the idea of creating datastructure, it's fast. Except one thing, I am using `compactMap` instead of `map`.

Comment: @Amit I wouldn't advise to do that. I know that `compactMap` might *feel* like you're "properly handling optionals", because you don't see any `!`. But really what you're doing is turning a loud noticeable failure (a crash) into a subtle silent failure (elements missing from your result). There might be times when that's appropriate, but I think it's better to either force unwrap (if you're sure `array1` should always have matches for the values in `array2`), or leave the `nil`s in place and handle them later.

Comment: yes you are right. However array1 always matches for the values in array2. But still I will check for both scenarios before integrating in the project. Thanks again buddy.

Comment: One more thing, Do you know the reason of downvote for the question ?

Comment: @Amit I don't know, but there are quite a few quality control issues with it. Using `[String: Any]` dicts where structs/class objects would be more appropriate, using hopelessly non-descriptive names like `array1` and `array2`, and a few english grammar issues

Comment: @Amit Generally it's a bad idea to name things like "userArray". The "arrayness" cold just be conveyed by plurality: `users`. And something like `userDict` could be called `usersById`, which shows the exact relationship between the keys and values

Answer (score 0):

Well after digging few more and with the help of this blog:

- https://medium.com/@abhimuralidharan/higher-order-functions-in-swift-filter-map-reduce-flatmap-1837646a63e8

I tried doing like this:

```
let results = userIds.compactMap { (int) -> User? in
    var matchedUser: User?
    if users.contains(where: { (user) -> Bool in
        if user.id == int {
            matchedUser = user
        }
        return user.id == int
    }) {
        return matchedUser
    }
    return nil
}
```

and in playground I checked the count the code was executed :

[image]

and it seems like the count is less comparing to "for" loop.